# How to override email address used by at command

Tags: cron, sendmail, exim, at

`cron` has `MAILTO` setting to explicitly configure the email address that will receive the report

Does `at` have anything of the kind?

Man page says it will send using `/usr/sbin/sendmail` but which destination address will be used?

I only have exim installed on that machine, and emails sent to @ are lost (neither `.forward` not mutt see any letters in the inbox).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Oded consider the answer below

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Thomas Koenig's `at` on a glibc (Linux) system (now [maintained by Jose Calhariz](https://packages.qa.debian.org/a/at.html)), it's possible but not documented clearly, from `at(1)`:

> If the file /var/run/utmp is not available or corrupted, or if the user
>      is not logged on at the time at is invoked, the mail  is  sent  to  the
>      userid found in the environment variable LOGNAME.  If that is undefined
>      or empty, the current userid is assumed.

The way `at` works is to construct a job file which `atd` uses, the first three lines of which are:

```
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=100 gid=100
# mail youruser 1
```

where `uid=100`, `gid=100` and `youruser` are determined programmatically when the job is being created. The logic for determining the username is:

1. call `getlogin()`
2. if that's NULL call `getenv("LOGNAME")`
3. check the name exists by calling `getpwnam()`
4. if that's NULL call `getpwuid(real_uid)`
5. if that's NULL throw all of the toys out of the pram

So, how can we convince `getlogin()` to return NULL in order to use the LOGNAME variable? One way is to arrange for stdin to *not* be a terminal (this is why I assume glibc, `getlogin()` behaves differently across systems).

To do this from `bash`:

```
LOGNAME=backup at 19:52 -m <<< uptime
echo uptime | LOGNAME=backup at 19:52 -m
```

The point is to use redirection to present the command(s) on stdin for `at` to run. (`at` also performs a *reopening* of stdin if you use its `-f` option, though too late to be of use here.) You can instead save your command to a file, or with bash to save creating a file:

```
LOGNAME=backup at 19:52 -m -f <( echo uptime ) 0<&-
```

(`0<&-` closes stdin, `< /dev/null` will also work)

If your terminal (or `screen` or `tmux`) disregards `utmp` (by configuration, or though permissions or helper problems), you can even just set `LOGNAME` and just use `at` as normal since `getlogin()` will fail. You can tell if this is the case by finding your terminal using `tty` and then checking `w` to see if you're properly logged in on that tty, or try `perl -E 'say getlogin()||"not-in-utmp";'` .

(Just to be clear, LOGNAME can only be a local username, if you need an email to go elsewhere you will need to use `aliases`/`.forward`/`procmail` etc.)